# Consuming ArcGIS Server map services from WCF

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight, wcf

I am consuming some map services in my WCF services and for each service that I have I get the client object via this code. Every new service that I add, I get the client object this way. I am curious if I can consume the map service using it's URL so that I dont have to add the map service as a service reference. I would like to use the URL of map service to create client object.

```
MapServerPortClient client = new WellMapService.MapServerPortClient(); 
OR
MapServerPortClient client = new PipelineMapService.MapServerPortClient();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the overloads which the generated client class constructor provides. It allows you to specify a different address upon the client instantiation.

```
new WellMapService.MapServerPortClient(
    "MapServerPort", // endpoint name (from app.config/web.config)
    "http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Population_World/MapServer" // url used instead of the one in the config file
    );
```